# I cloned a flutter project from github on my sytem n got the following error when i tried to get the required packages

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

flutter pub-get Error reading LocalFile: '/../rider/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' even though it exists. Please ensure that you have read permission to this file and try again. exit code 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yELbP.png)

Comment: Can you share your project structure and where you've cloned it?

Comment: yeah! I have added it to the description.